# how to getting parents value

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you see I have more than one `.box` div and my `.box` div has  `data-item-color` attribute I need to get `data-item-color` value to change my `.box` css properties (.line,.tinyline,h6,p), shortly:

if my `data-item-color` has `red` value than make my `.line`,`h6`,`p` to red which is inside of `.box` div

and [demo link](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/RKmWvj)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

```css
h6,
p,
span {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

.tinyline:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-item-color="red">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>RED</h6>
  <p>red text...
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="box" data-item-color="blue">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>BLUE</h6>
  <p>Blue text..
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I also edited your css):

```
<div class="box" data-item-color="red">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>RED</h6>
  <p>red text...
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="box" data-item-color="blue">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>BLUE</h6>
  <p>Blue text..
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('data-item-color');
    $(this).children('.line').addClass(color);
    $(this).children('h6').css('color', color);
    $(this).children('p').css('color', color);
    $(this).find('.tinyline').addClass(color);
  });
});
```

```css
h6,
p,
span {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

.line.red:before {
  background: red;
}

.line.blue:before {
  background: blue;
}

.tinyline:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

.tinyline.red:after {
  background: red;
}

.tinyline.blue:after {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-item-color="red">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>RED</h6>
  <p>red text...
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="box" data-item-color="blue">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>BLUE</h6>
  <p>Blue text..
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I saw your comment so I edited the code. If you really need pseudo element You can create a class for each color You are going to use. Then in jquery You will overwrite the line:before and tinyline:after style you wrote before by adding the relative class to the element.

Comment: hi thanks for sharing I wonder something why not .line or .tinyline doesn't change could it be because of psuedo?

Comment: @recruit_man pseudo elements can't be manipulated directly by javascript. Looking at your css i saw that the pseudo elements were not needed so i removed them

Comment: buy in my project I have to reach them because I'm using flaticon and font is chancing only just before psuedo of flaticon font

Comment: I know I can maket it using css :))

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this.

I traversed through each div and applied its color to its child.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.box").each(function(){
    $(this).find("*").css("color",$(this).data("item-color"));
    $(this).find(".line,.tinyline").css("background-color",$(this).data("item-color"));
  });
});
```

```css
h6,
p,
span {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.line {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

.tinyline {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-item-color="red">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>RED</h6>
  <p>red text...
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="box" data-item-color="blue">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>BLUE</h6>
  <p>Blue text..
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: it's great I have another question how can I change my psuedo properties how they will change ?

Comment: You have to remove `:after` and `:before` from css for that.

Comment: I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 1):

Tell me is it ok this answer?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

window["GETATRR"] = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

 for (var x=0;x < GETATRR.length ;x++) {
    if ( typeof GETATRR[x].getAttribute("data-item-color") != 'undefined'  ) {
     console.log("I AM : " + GETATRR[x].getAttribute("data-item-color"))
    // CHANGE HERE WHAT EVER YOU WANT 
    GETATRR[x].style.color = GETATRR[x].getAttribute("data-item-color")
    }
 } 
});
```

```css
h6,
p,
span {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

.tinyline:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-item-color="red">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>RED</h6>
  <p>red text...
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="box" data-item-color="blue">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <h6>BLUE</h6>
  <p>Blue text..
    <span class="tinyline"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it's a good example thanks for it but there is anything else that I wonder now how to change properties of psuedo(before,after) with jquery ? :)

Comment: Add red , blue ... class , than use find child elements of current .box(tag element) , easy with JQ remove and add new class , red for red etc... Just follow stackoverflow Q/A your solution is already there.